# Marginal Distributions obtained by restricting a 2D Gaussian to a circle

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

Suppose I have a 2D Gaussian
$$
f(x, y) = \frac{1}{2\pi\,\sqrt{\text{det}(\Sigma)}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(\boldsymbol{x}- \boldsymbol{\mu})^\top \Sigma^{-1} (\boldsymbol{x}- \boldsymbol{\mu})\right\} \qquad \text{with } \boldsymbol{\mu}=(\mu_x, \mu_y)^\top
$$
and then I restrict it to be on a circle. For simplicity, I assume the circle is centered at the mean of the Gaussian
$$
\mathcal{C}=\left\{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\, :\, (x - \mu_x)^2 + (y - \mu_y)^2 = 1\right\}
$$
What does the marginal distributions become? Here's a short picture of what I mean:

- First, we have a 2D Gaussian, denoted here by light grey contours
- Then we restrict the distribution to only take values on the unit circle (blue)
- Finally, we marginalize on the x and y axis.

[image]

I have seen [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268443447_Recursive_Bingham_Filter_for_Directional_Estimation_Involving_180_Degree_Symmetry/figures?lo=1) that maybe the distribution on the circle is a Bingham distribution but that's as far as I can go. Any hint?

## Following the Answer

I think the idea is that if we have a point $(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ then we can map this to be on the unit circle centred at the origin using the mapping
$$
g:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 \qquad (x, y) \longmapsto \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)
$$
The Jacobian of this transformation is given by
$$
J_g(x, y) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
     \frac{y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} & - \frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \\
- \frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} & \frac{x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \end{pmatrix}
$$
Its determinant is, unfortunately, zero
$$
\text{det}(J_g(x, y)) = \frac{x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3}} - \frac{x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3}} = 0
$$
Since what we want is the distribution of
$$
u = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
$$
we now instead consider a different function:
$$
g_2:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2 \qquad (x, y)\mapsto \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, y\right)
$$

This function **does not** map $\mathbb{R}^2$ into the unit circle centred at the origin. However, conveniently, its first coordinate is the same as the one we want to find the distribution of. Our goal is then this:

- Use the change of variable formula to find the joint distribution of
  $$
  (u, v) = \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, y\right)
  $$
- Marginalize over $v$ to obtain the distribution for $u$
  $$
  p(u) = \int p(u, v) dv
  $$

The Jacobian of this transformation is
$$
J_{g_2}(x, y) = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} & - \frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
It's determinant is
$$
\text{det}(J_{g_2}(x, y)) = \frac{y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
$$
The change of variable formula then tells us
$$
\begin{align}
f_{U\times V}(u, v) 
&= f_{X\times Y}(g_2^{-1}(u, v)) \cdot |\text{det}(J_{g_2}(x, y)|^{-1}_{(x, y) = g_2^{-1}(u, v)} 
\end{align}
$$
One can easily find $g_2^{-1}(u, v)$ since $y = v$ and
$$
u^2 = \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} \quad \implies \quad u^2(x^2 + v^2) = x^2 \quad \implies \quad x^2 = \frac{u^2v^2}{1 - u^2}\quad \implies \quad x = \frac{|uv|}{(1 - u^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}
$$
Pluggin this into the Jacobian we get
$$
|\text{det}(J_{g_2})(x, y)|_{(x, y) = g_2^{-1}(u,v)}  = \frac{y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} = \frac{(1 - u^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{|v|}
$$
Thefore the joint distribution on $(u, v)$ is
$$
f_{U\times V}(u, v) = f_{X\times Y}\left(\frac{|uv|}{(1 - u^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}, v\right) \frac{|v|}{(1 - u^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
$$

Since $(x, y) \mapsto \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, y\right)$ we can see that this distribution is defined over $[-1, 1]\times \mathbb{R}$. Now we can perform the second step and marginalize with respect to $v$
$$
\begin{align}
    f_U(u) 
    &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{U\times V}(u, v) dv \\
    &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{X\times Y}\left(\frac{|uv|}{(1 - u^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}, v\right) \frac{|v|}{(1 - u^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} dv
\end{align}
$$
Consider the bivariate normal distribution
$$
{\displaystyle f_{X\times Y}(x,y)={\frac {1}{2\pi \sigma _{X}\sigma _{Y}{\sqrt {1-\rho ^{2}}}}}\mathrm {e} ^{-{\frac {1}{2(1-\rho ^{2})}}\left[({\frac {x-\mu _{X}}{\sigma _{X}}})^{2}-2\rho ({\frac {x-\mu _{X}}{\sigma _{X}}})({\frac {y-\mu _{Y}}{\sigma _{Y}}})+({\frac {y-\mu _{Y}}{\sigma _{Y}}})^{2}\right]}}
$$
Choosing $\Sigma = I_2$ (i.e. $\sigma_x = \sigma_y = 1$ and $\rho=0$) and centered at $\mu = (0, 0)$ we get
$$
f_{X\times Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left\{-\frac{\left(x^2+y^2\right)}{2}\right\}
$$
Now plugging in
$$
x^2 + y^2 = \frac{v^2}{1 - u^2}
$$
we obtain
$$
f_{X\times Y}(g_2^{-1}(u, v)) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left\{-\frac{v^2}{2(1 - u^2)}\right\}
$$
Marginalizing we get
$$
\begin{align}
    f_U(u) 
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left\{-\frac{v^2}{2(1 - u^2)}\right\}  \frac{|v|}{(1 - u^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} dv \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{1 - u^2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp\left\{-\frac{v^2}{2(1 - u^2)}\right\} \frac{|v|}{(1 - u^2)} dv \\
&= - \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{1 - u^2}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} - \frac{|v|}{(1 - u^2)}\exp\left\{-\frac{v^2}{2(1 - u^2)}\right\}  dv \\
&= -\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-u^2}} \int_{0}^{\infty} - \frac{|v|}{(1 - u^2)}\exp\left\{-\frac{v^2}{2(1 - u^2)}\right\}  dv && \text{even}\\
&= -\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-u^2}}\left[\exp\left\{-\frac{v^2}{2(1 - u^2)}\right\}\right]_0^{\infty} \\
&= -\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-u^2}}\left[0 - 1\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-u^2}}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $\mu_x=\mu_y=0$ for simplicity. The joint pdf of $U:=X/\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ and $V:=Y$ is given by
\begin{align}
f_{U,V}(u,v)&=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x(u,v),y(u,v))}{|\partial (u,v)/\partial(x,y)|_{x=u|v|/(1-u^2)^{1/2},y=v}} \\
&=f_{X,Y}\!\left(u|v|/(1-u^2)^{1/2},v\right)\times\frac{|v|}{(1-u^2)^{3/2}}
\end{align}
over $(-1,1)\times\mathbb{R}$. Then the marginal density of $U$ is
$$
f_U(u)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}\!\left(u|v|/(1-u^2)^{1/2},v\right)\times\frac{|v|}{(1-u^2)^{3/2}}\, dv.
$$
For example, when $\Sigma=I_2$,
$$
f_{U}(u)=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-u^2}}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am a bit confused. Where did you get the expression from $U$ and $V$ from?

Comment: $U$ is the random variable whose density you're looking for (when $\mu_x$ and $\mu_y$ are $0$). The rest is the standard technique for finding the pdf of transformed r.v.s. In particular, in the first step we need to introduce an auxiliary r.v. ($V$) to be able to compute the Jacobian of the transformation.

Comment: I am just trying to figure out how you got to $U = \frac{X}{\sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}}$. Do you mind helping me out a bit more?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you want to "restrict" $(X,Y)$ to a unit circle. Now,
$$
\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}},\frac{Y}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}\right)
$$
is the transformation that sends $(X,Y)$ to the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$.

Comment: Yes exactly! So I don't care about anything outside of the circle. I was looking for a transformation that would send the $\mathbb{R}^2$ space to the circle but I couldn't come up with anything sensible. I tried the route of going into polar coordinates but that didn't work.

Comment: So then okay you've got a transformation $g(x, y) = (\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})$ and you use the change of variable formula?

Comment: What I am confused about is also why do you define $v=y$ rather than $v=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Comment: Btw, when $\Sigma_{11}=\Sigma_{22}=1$ and $\Sigma_{12}=\rho\in(-1,1)$,
$$
f_U(u)=\frac{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}{\pi(\sqrt{1-u^2}-2\rho u(1-u^2))}.
$$
(Need to check that.)

Comment: Thank you so much! How would it change for a non-zero mean?

Comment: If $\mu_x\ne 0$, the density of $U$ becomes $u\mapsto f_U(u-\mu_x)$ with $u\in (\mu_x-1,\mu_x+1)$.

Comment: I will definitely accept the answer, I am just trying to verify everything myself!

Comment: If we use $v=y/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, the determinant of the Jacobian becomes $0$, which is equivalent to the fact that $(U,V)$ in that case doesn't have a density w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: WAIT! Surely if you have a point $$(u, v) = \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, y\right)$$ then this is not necessarily on the circle. Indeed if I take any $(x, y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ then I will have $u^2 + v^2 = \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} + y^2 \neq 1$

Comment: Can you give me some reference to this mapping? I am honestly so confused.

Comment: OK. The final goal is to find the distribution of the first coordinate of $(X/\sqrt{X^2+Y^2},Y/\sqrt{X^2+Y^2})$, and we don't care about the second coordinate. We introduce $V=Y$ (auxiliary variable) in order to compute that distribution using the [standard technique](http://bit.ly/2NLVmbE).

Comment: Makes sense now I think! I have essentially re-written your answer in my question, do you think the motivations make sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you! Last thing: what am I doing wrong in the final integration? I should probably get $2$ but I get $0$

Comment: Actually,it should be -2

Comment: \begin{align}
 \int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp\left\{-\frac{v^2}{2(1 - u^2)}\right\} \frac{|v|}{(1 - u^2)} \,dv&=2\int_0^{\infty}\exp\left\{-\frac{v^2}{2(1 - u^2)}\right\} \frac{v}{(1 - u^2)} \,dv \\
&=2\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}\,dx=2.
\end{align}